# Can I record audio in AMP (accelerated mobile pages)?

Tags: amp-html

Can I record audio in amp-pages? As additional JS is not allowed in amp-pages.

I am not able to find any thing regarding this on google.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean embedding audio files on AMP pages like podcasts, you can use [the amp-audio component.](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-audio/)

If you actually want users to record themselves on your website, you can't do it with AMP. 
What you can do is have the rest of the site in AMP and the page where they record, code it outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a separate page that deals with this functionality (could be just a button that calls [`getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) or uses [`<input type="file" capture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#capture)) and then include it in your AMP page by using [`<amp-iframe>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-iframe/).